# EXCEL Summing values YTD based on Criteria (Offset Index Match)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say...

1. I have Jan - Dec data, say columns B : K.
2. Then I have the row labels in column A (Sales, COGS, Travel Expenses, etc...).
3. Then on a summary screen, I have a data validation list where the user can choose the month for a Year-to-Date calculation.

I swore I've been able to calculate YTD based off a data validation list in the past using SUMIF(Column A, (Criteria), Offset (Jan) : Index(match) the column # based off of the month selection)

So Mar would move the range from Jan to Mar, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `SUMIF` use just `SUM` with `INDEX` and `MATCH` like:

```
=SUM(INDEX(B:B,MATCH([criteria],A:A,0)):INDEX(B:K,MATCH([criteria],A:A,0),[count of month]))
```

for `[count of month]` use 6 for January to June.
the only you can not do is summing up multiple rows at once.

Comment: Thank you Dirk,  I did not think to expand the 2nd part of the range "B:K".